# jQuery tab width if increased, on click doesn't open the intended tab

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

If I increase the size of jQuery tab, on click on the portion of the tab where text isn't present doesn't load the intended tab. Clicking on the header works. But clicking on the empty portion isn't working. 
[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/PUCnU/5/)

I increased the width this way.

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
 width:180px;
}
```

Does anyone know the fix?

Comment: use a instead of li .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav a{
   width:180px;
}   http://jsfiddle.net/PUCnU/6/

Comment: Thank you. That works great. But I've one more small problem. I've set tab closable property to true. Now If use your code, x mark for the tab comes in the bottom instead of right top

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your styles:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

That way the anchor will take up the whole width and be clickable.

Comment: Thank you. That works great. But I've one more small problem. I've set tab closable property to true. Now If use your code, x mark for the tab comes in the bottom instead of right top.

Comment: You can try adjusting the width of the anchor in order to make space for the "X".

Comment: After some testing it seems that using width: 139px; should work